# SQL: Subquery? Pulling column using condition

Tags: mysql, sql

Current SQL code is:

```
    SELECT k.id, k.symbol, y.close, y.volume, 
((y.close / y.close_adj_previous_day)-1) AS percent_change
        FROM symbols k
        JOIN stocks y ON k.id = y.id
    WHERE 
        k.t_removed = 0
        AND t = '$max_t'
    ORDER BY percent_change DESC
    LIMIT 10
```

Trying to get the close_adj_previous_day.  Currently I use another query to get the close_adj_previous day as such:

```
        SELECT k.close_adj AS close_adj_previous_day
        FROM stocks k
        WHERE 
            k.id = '$id'
            AND k.t = '$max_t_minus_one'
        LIMIT 1
```

How would I combine these queries, to get the result to be sorted as the top query?  Thanks guys/gals.

Semi example from table:

[Example Table Kind Of](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYLHW.png)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help your query.

Comment: I added an image as a semi-example table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the variables, use a `join`:
You have the previous day value in a variable.  You can just use a `join`:

```
SELECT k.id, k.symbol, y.close, y.volume, 
   ((y.close / yprev.close)-1) AS percent_change,
   yprev.close_adj AS close_adj_previous_day
FROM symbols k JOIN
     stocks y
     ON k.id = y.id AND y.t = '$max_t' JOIN
     stocks yprev
     ON k.id = yprev.id and yprev.t = '$max_t_minus_one'
WHERE k.t_removed = 0
ORDER BY percent_change DESC
LIMIT 10
```